# If statement inside another if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo, while-loop

I'm struggling with this IF statement.  I'm trying to make any cell that is older than today turn red, but all the cells are turning red.  I'm sure it's an obvious mistake but I can't see the wood for the trees.

The IF statement at line 59 is the one I am having issues with.  I want the option for checking the date on all columns but am trailing with "Not Started" first.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  $notstarted = array();
  $intransit = array();
  $awaiting = array();
  $built = array();
  $cfc2 = array();
  $received = array();
  $date_created = array();
  $date = date('Y-m-d');

  try {    
    //open the PDO-connection to a MySQL-host
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$daba", $user, $pass);

    //error mode set to EXCEPTION (ERRMODE_SILENT or ERRMODE_WARNING are also possible)
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    //execute the query
    $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT status, ticket, site, date_created FROM stores ORDER BY ticket');

    //set default fetch mode to FETCH_ASSOC (if you want to try FETCH_OBJ)
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }

  //go through all results and assign them to the related arrays
  while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $data = $row['ticket'] . '&nbsp; (' . $row['site'] . ')';
    if ($row['status'] == "Not Started") { $notstarted[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "In Transit") { $intransit[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "Awaiting Build") { $awaiting[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "Being Built") { $built[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "On Return from CFC2") { $cfc2[] = $data; }
    if ($row['status'] == "Received") { $received[] = $data; }
  }

  //close the connection
  $DBH = null;
?>



<table align="center" border="1" width="90%">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FDFEAD"><font face="Arial"><strong>Not Started</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FDFEAD"><font face="Arial"><strong>In Transit</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FDFEAD"><font face="Arial"><strong>Awaiting Build</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FDFEAD"><font face="Arial"><strong>Being Built</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FDFEAD"><font face="Arial"><strong>On Return</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FDFEAD"><font face="Arial"><strong>Received Back</strong></font></td>
      </tr>

      <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($notstarted),count($intransit),count($awaiting),count($built),count($cfc2),count($received)); $i++) {
          echo "<tr>";


    if (count($notstarted) > $i) {
        if ($row['date_created'] <= $date) {
        echo "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"red\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
    } else {
        echo "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#BCBBBB\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
    }
            echo $notstarted[$i];
            echo "</font></td>";
    }


          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($intransit) > $i) echo $intransit[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($awaiting) > $i) echo $awaiting[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($built) > $i) echo $built[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($cfc2) > $i) echo $cfc2[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#95FA95\"><font face=\"Arial\">";
          if (count($received) > $i) echo $received[$i];
          echo "</font></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
      ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: When posting code in your Q/A you should *at least* format your code properly (there are tons of tools for that online). This would make it a lot easier to look at your code and give suggestions and answers. Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: change `if ($row['date_created'] <= $date) {` to `if (strtotime($row['date_created']) <= strtotime($date) ){` and check

Comment: Coops, since you probably don't get a notification for this, Cody was kind enough to move our comment thread to chat - it will be better served there. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152776

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare dates with the `<`(less than) operator.

```
if(strtotime($row['date_created']) <= time()) {
    red logic
} else {
    non-red logic
}
```

You may want to read up on [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

There are a number of other issues with your code you should clean up, first and foremost being indentation. The part of your code with the problem was incredibly difficult to process mentally due to the indentation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152776/discussion-on-answer-by-corsika-if-statement-inside-another-if-statement). If you are having a problem getting this code to work, edit your question. If you have a follow-up question, ask a new question (if necessary, include a link to this one to provide context).